# Problems when adding vertical line to array and converting RMarkdown document to Word

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown, pandoc

I'm trying to add vertical lines to LaTeX arrays in my RMarkdown document. The preview in RStudio, the conversion to html and pdf work like a charm. There seems to be a problem when I try to convert this document to word:

```
---
title: "Array"
output: word_document
---

$$
\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 2 \\
3 & 4 \\
\end{array}
$$

$$
\begin{array}{c|c}
1 & 2 \\
3 & 4 \\
\end{array}
$$
```

The first array prints correctly but the second (where I added the vertical line) doesn't print at all. In the word document created, only the LaTeX code appears. When I compile, here is the error message I receives:

```
[WARNING] Could not convert TeX math '
\begin{array}{c|c}
1 & 2 \\
3 & 4 \\
\end{array}
', rendering as TeX:

               ^
unexpected "|"
expecting letter, white space or "}"
```

I'm currently using Word 2016.

Thanks

Comment: what version of `pandoc` are you using?

Comment: I tried several tests with [`texmath`](https://github.com/jgm/texmath): I think this feature is not supported by `pandoc`. You should open a feature request.

Comment: Thank you [romles](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6500804/romles) for your tests. I will probably open a feature request.